# Kubernetes scaling up not fast enough (for K8 1.17 or below)

Tags: kubernetes, scaling, hpa

Kubernetes 1.18 has a very nice ability to change auto-scaling going up through the behavior and scaleUp set. For 1.17, there's a way to control downscaling. Is there a parallel way to scale up faster? We are expecting very variable loads and our cluster isn't scaling up fast enough.

I am not sure what other info to include. I've been searching through the docs, but I cannot find anything that points me in the right direction.

Comment: Which type of scaling are you working with? HPA, VPA, Cluster Autoscaler?

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

Assuming you are referring to HPAs, you can define a behavior [scaleUp Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#default-behavior) only if you are using [K8s 1.18 or later (*`v2beta2`* HPA API)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-configurable-scaling-behavior). For example:

```yaml
behavior:
  scaleDown:
    stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
    policies:
    - type: Percent
      value: 100
      periodSeconds: 15
  scaleUp: 
    stabilizationWindowSeconds: 0
    policies:
    - type: Percent
      value: 100
      periodSeconds: 15
    - type: Pods
      value: 4
      periodSeconds: 15
    selectPolicy: Max
```

[image: Autoscaling API]

✌️

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was hoping to find a way to do it in 1.17.

Comment: I read your question too fast. So this is not even available on 1.17 with a feature gate.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I think we'll just have to move to 1.18. Thanks for looking!